# Eclipse 1.7 Error: '[File name]' has encountered a prob'. Cannot connect to VM

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

I wasn't allowed to use the word problem in the title, but I was just quoting an error message.
So I am getting the error stated in the title as such:

[image]

Details simply state: 'Cannot connect to VM. Socket closed'.

---

In the console I have: Invalid memory access of location 0x14 rip=0x10a574a84

(Which didn't give me much of a lead.)

I've checked my Security and Privacy preferences, restarted all applications and even turned off my firewall. I checked a few answers on here but they were all windows based.

**EDIT: (More information in console)**

> FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized,
>   jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197) ERROR: transport error 202:
>   gethostbyname: unknown host ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to
>   initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510) JDWP exit error
>   AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized
>   [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:750]

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you pressed "Allow" and then tried again? I ask because if the socket is denied by the OS, then you could easily get a "cannot connect to VM. Socket closed" error.

Comment: @JonahGraham - Yeah, I've managed to click the allow but that pop-up stays up for 1 second before closing itself. Nothing happened mind.

Comment: The pop-up that is disappearing after 1 second is almost certainly the key to your problem. I'm sorry that no one is giving you an actual answer (i.e I am only commenting, not answering). I would revisit your [macosx firewall settings](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201642) again.

Comment: @JonahGraham - I've been through the suggested link and unfortunately not much has changed, I did receive more errors in the console which I've added to the question. I'll poke around a little more.